# Regex Pattern that contains number between 0-99 and also allow up to 2 digit decimal point

Tags: html, angular, angular-cli

For angular app,
We need validation like the user can enter between 0-99 and also can enter up to 2 digit decimal points.

For example,

- 0 -> Pass
- 0.1 -> Pass
- 1.12 -> pass
- 12.12 -> Pass
- 100 -> Fail
- 19.111 -> Fail
- 1.-> Fail

`^[0-9]+([.][0-9]{1,2})?$` this pattern is working for other cases apart from case( 100 -> Fail)

for that I tried pattern something like `^([0-9]{1,2})+([.][0-9]{1,2})?$` but it's not working as expected.

Please suggest a pattern that covers all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made the below pattern with the help of [wnvko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4398005/wnvko) and [Sameshostee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17861194/sameshostee) answers, it's working properly with this Validators.pattern('...').

Thanks @wnvko and @Sameshostee for your help.

`^(?:99|[0-9]{1,2})([.][0-9]{1,2})?$`

Comment: keep in mind this will also match two digit number starting with zero like 01, 02 and so on!

Answer (score 2):

`/^(?:99|\d{1,2})(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/`

- ^ - beginning of string
- (?:99|\d{1,2}) - non-capturing group, 0-99
- (?:.\d{1,2})? - optional non-capturing group (.# or .##)
- $ - end of string

That should be it, please test it further.

Comment: I tried to put a pattern like ```Validators.pattern('^(?:99|\d{1,2})(?:\.\d{1,2})?$')``` but nothing working 
I give 11.11,1, 1.11 but in all cases the form is not going to be valid. Let me know if I made any mistakes

Comment: I believe the regex should work. https://regex101.com/r/qGy9BA/1

Possibly something with Validators.pattern or your form.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with something like this

```
/^(?:[1-9][0-9]?|0)(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/
```

Here’s how it works:

- ^ matches the start of the string.
- (?:[1-9][0-9]?|0) matches any number between 0 and 99
- (?:.[0-9]{1,2})? matches up to two digits after the decimal point
- $ matches the end of the string

This will not match 09

Comment: Validators.pattern('^(?:[1-9][0-9]?|0)(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$')

This pattern is not working When I give `100` or something 3 digit value other than this it's working fine. Let me know If I missed anything

Comment: what you mean not working. Tested this with 100, 222, 999 and some other 3 digit numbers and it does not select any of them.

Comment: Maybe something problem with Validators.pattern()